# How to do the performance measurement of website manually by coding?? Any Idea

Tags: performance, optimization, traffic-measurement

I have to develop the application to check the performance of the website .. 
I need some guidance about how can I do it with coding.I have searched a lot but google is giving only tools for doing that. anyone have any Idea about this?..suggest me some path where I should work upon.Help will be appreciated.Waiting for your responses.

I have seen manny sites are giving results on the basis of the pages of our websites so they might be getting the pages from the sitemap,that is my point of view I don't know the rest.I think they might be getting the page and logging the load time and response time that is what I have thought but still I am not Knowing how log that things ..I need your guidance to proceed further Thank you.

Comment: I have search for this topic and come to know about the pagespeed tool which helps to know about the page.It has tool as well as provides the API to which will give the result of the page to us as well as we can show that result as google o meter  and it also provides suggestion to improve the score but still I need to work with the API but I want to create my own tool  who can measure the performance  of website please guide me or show me some path for this...Thank you